# Does Aid Another Break Invisibility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, invisibility

When using the Aid Another action, does it break invisibility? I'm inclined to say no, because you're not actually attacking a creature, you're making an attack roll against a flat AC of 10.

> [Aid Another](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Aid-Another)
>
> In melee combat, you can help a friend attack or defend by distracting
>   or interfering with an opponent. If you're in position to make a melee
>   attack on an opponent that is engaging a friend in melee combat, you
>   can attempt to aid your friend as a standard action. You make an
>   attack roll against AC 10. If you succeed, your friend gains either a
>   +2 bonus on his next attack roll against that opponent or a +2 bonus to AC against that opponent's next attack (your choice), as long as
>   that attack comes before the beginning of your next turn. Multiple
>   characters can aid the same friend, and similar bonuses stack.
>
> You can also use this standard action to help a friend in other ways,
>   such as when he is affected by a spell, or to assist another
>   character's skill check.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**, it does end. The general rules for magic state:

> Some spell descriptions refer to attacking. All offensive combat actions, even those that don't damage opponents, are considered attacks.

Aiding Another, because it either makes an opponent more vulnerable to attack or less able to attack back, is an offensive combat action. Here are the rules again, appropriately emphasized:

> In melee combat, you can help a friend attack or defend by **distracting or interfering with an opponent**. If you’re **in position to make a melee attack on an opponent** that is engaging a friend in melee combat, you can attempt to aid your friend as a standard action. You make an attack roll against AC 10. If you succeed, your friend gains either a +2 bonus on his next attack roll **against that opponent** or a +2 bonus to AC **against that opponent**’s next attack (your choice)

It's clear that this is directed specifically against a *particular* foe, and that you must be able to attack *that foe* in melee, and that your actions are directed *against* that foe. That's a textbook non-damaging offensive combat action.

Comment: With Mirror Image, the images can't be targeted directly (not least because the attacker can't know whether they're targeting an image or the original). They don't have an independent AC: they're destroyed based on the attack roll against the creature affected. So, Aid Another could be used to help your friend hit a creature affected by Mirror Image, which may translate into more easily destroying a mirror, but an "Aid Another against a Mirror Image" doesn't really make sense. I'm not sure how to clean up that last paragraph, though.

Comment: @minnmass: Seems the last paragraph only really works in 3.5.

Comment: ... and, even in 3.5, it's awkward: you still generally can't target just an image, but must target the creature (and use the image's AC to see if you hit it if you happened to be swinging at it).

Answer (score 7):

I'd say **yes**, aid another does break invisibility.

Strictly going by the RAW we have from the [Invisibility spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/invisibility.html#invisibility):

> The spell ends if the subject attacks any creature. For purposes of this spell, an attack includes any spell targeting a foe or whose area or effect includes a foe.

From the [aid another action](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#aid-another), which you quote:

> If you're in position to make a melee attack on an opponent that is engaging a friend in melee combat, you can attempt to aid your friend as a standard action. You make an attack roll against AC 10.

**Short story**: You make an attack and the spell ends.

**Longer story, based on the comments**: Granted, the description of the aid another action does not explicitly say that the attack roll is directed at the opponent. However, an [attack roll](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#attack-roll) presupposes an opponent. Thus the attack roll is targeted at the opponent.

Comment: But what would happen when using the aid another action to assist on a skill check or when an ally is affected by a spell?

Comment: Again, I would like to put forth the implications were aid another described to "hit" an opponent. Someone using aid another could gain the benefit of the critical feats and apply conditions to their target were they to critical hit. Would Aid Another then Destroy a Mirror Image on the target? There are a lot of things that can go wrong with this.

Comment: @MrTumnus That's an important distinction. Destroying a Mirror Image at 10 AC would change a majority of melee magician tactics.

Answer (score -2):

To break invisibility: Attack another creature.

To aid another: Attack AC 10.

AC 10 is not a creature.

Another poster interprets "all offensive combat actions are considered attacks" to mean anything that "either makes an opponent more vulnerable to attack or less able to attack back, is an offensive combat action". Under that kind of interpretation, buffing yourself for combat is an attack if it improves your attack bonus.

Under that interpretation, becoming invisible would be an offensive action and immediately make you not invisible again, since it does both of those things. So would casting Expeditious Retreat. Or using a single move action to move your speed. Tripping an opponent for no damage is offensive. Disarming an opponent for no damage is offensive. Aiding your friend is not offensive any more than casting the Haste spell is.

Comment: There's a distinction between making **an opponent** more vulnerable to attack, and making **an ally** more able to attack. This distinction is utterly critical, not merely for *invisibility*, but for the entire concept of spells with saves or SR: it's the difference between casting *bless* on your party members and *bane* on your enemies.

Comment: @TuggyNE Doesn't using Aid Another fall into the second camp, then? When using Aid Another, you're making an ally more able to attack. You're providing an additional +2 ATK.

Comment: @Axoren: See my answer, but the short version is no, you're making the opponent more vulnerable, which happens to give an ally +2 to attacking *them*.